# my Angular app is not working in GitHub pages

Tags: angular, github

I am having trouble getting my Angular app to work on GitHub pages. This is my first Angular app I have tried many solutions nothing work

Angular.json

```
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "todo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "outputPath": "dist/todo",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ],
              "outputHashing": "all"
            },
            "development": {
              "buildOptimizer": false,
              "optimization": false,
              "vendorChunk": true,
              "extractLicenses": false,
              "sourceMap": true,
              "namedChunks": true
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "todo:build:production"
            },
            "development": {
              "browserTarget": "todo:build:development"
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "development"
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "todo:build"
          }
        },
        "test": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:karma",
          "options": {
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js",
              "zone.js/testing"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.spec.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Todo</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

after I deploy my app to GitHub pages. I got this errors and white page.

picture from the console

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uJQRp.png)

and from Network tab

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/71iVj.png)

more informtion about tools I use
Angular CLI: 15.1.6

#### Node: 18.16.0

#### Package Manager: npm 9.5.1

#### OS: win32 x64

#### Angular: 15.1.5

#### ... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms

#### ... platform-browser, platform-browser-dynamic, router

#### Package                         Version

#### ---------------------------------------------------------

#### @angular-devkit/architect       0.1501.6

#### @angular-devkit/build-angular   15.1.6

#### @angular-devkit/core            15.1.6

#### @angular-devkit/schematics      15.1.6

#### @angular/cli                    15.1.6

#### @schematics/angular             15.1.6

#### rxjs                            7.8.0

#### typescript

I tried to change angular.json too. but I got many problems. and I don't know why but the command
ng build --prod --base-href https://github.com/Todos.git
Error: Unknown argument: prod
always not working I use this command instead
$ ng build --configuration production --base-href /Todos/

````
{
  "$schema": "./node_modules/@angular/cli/lib/config/schema.json",
  "version": 1,
  "newProjectRoot": "projects",
  "projects": {
    "todo": {
      "projectType": "application",
      "schematics": {},
      "root": "",
      "sourceRoot": "src",
      "prefix": "app",
      "architect": {
        "build": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:browser",
          "options": {
            "baseHref": "/TodoList/",
            "deployUrl": "/TodoList/",
            "outputPath": "dist",
            "index": "src/index.html",
            "main": "src/main.ts",
            "polyfills": [
              "zone.js"
            ],
            "tsConfig": "tsconfig.app.json",
            "assets": [
              "src/favicon.ico",
              "src/assets"
            ],
            "styles": [
              "src/styles.css"
            ],
            "scripts": []
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "fileReplacements": [
                {
                  "replace": "src/environments/environment.ts",
                  "with": "src/environments/environment.prod.ts"
                }
              ],
              "optimization": true,
              "outputHashing": "all",
              "sourceMap": false,
              "namedChunks": false,
              "aot": true,
              "extractLicenses": true,
              "vendorChunk": false,
              "buildOptimizer": true,
              "budgets": [
                {
                  "type": "initial",
                  "maximumWarning": "500kb",
                  "maximumError": "1mb"
                },
                {
                  "type": "anyComponentStyle",
                  "maximumWarning": "2kb",
                  "maximumError": "4kb"
                }
              ]
            }
          },
          "defaultConfiguration": "production"
        },
        "serve": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:dev-server",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "todo:build"
          },
          "configurations": {
            "production": {
              "browserTarget": "todo:build:production"
            }
          }
        },
        "extract-i18n": {
          "builder": "@angular-devkit/build-angular:extract-i18n",
          "options": {
            "browserTarget": "todo:build",
            "extractCss": true
          }
        },
        "deploy": {
          "builder": "angular-cli-ghpages:deploy",
          "options": {
            "repo": "https://github.com/afaf99/TodoList.git",
            "branch": "gh-pages",
            "name": "Todo List",
            "email": "afaf@example.com",
            "baseHref": "/TodoList/",
            "no-silent": true
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}```
````

Comment: can you compare the url to which you are connecting, and the url used in the network tab to access the `main.js` file ? Can you show the base-href which is filled in your browser's HTML (inside the `<head>` tag) ? As you noticed, Github pages need a base-href, you have to check what's wrong in your actual base-href.